# Unable to get files from the find results into a tar file

Tags: find, io-redirection, tar

Below is my find command that searches and dumps the searched file results to `/tmp/findall.log`

```
find /app/test -type d  \( -name logs -o -name 'logs*' -o -name 'tmp*' \) -prune -o -print | tee  /tmp/findall.log
```

I can see stage folder in the find results as below:

```
grep stage /tmp/findall.log | more
/app/test/Server2/stage_02032020
/app/test/Server2/stage_02032020/Buyers
/app/test/Server2/stage_02032020/Buyers/BuyersQuote.xlsx
/app/test/Server2/stage_02032020/Buyers/xml
```

I then decided to tar the files found in the `find` results using the below command.

```
find /app/test -type d  \( -name logs -o -name 'logs*' -o -name 'tmp*' \) -prune -o  -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cvf /app/test_Backup.tar
```

However my tar file does not have the stage folders as was see with the find results as seen below.

```
tar -tvf test_Backup.tar | grep stage
No results Found.
```

Can you please suggest why are the files from the find results missing from the tar file?

Comment: How many entries does you `findall.log` file end up having. If there are _many_, then it is likely that your `tar` command is being invoked several times. You could you try `tar -cf test.tar -L findall.log` instead? Are you still on an AIX system?

Comment: This is a typical case for`star` and it's builtin `find` based on`libfind`.

Comment: Are you using GNU findutils? AIX versions don't support options `-print0` (find) and `-0` (xargs)

Answer (score 0):

may be "find" its passing an empty string or something like that, you can troubleshoot that with "--no-run-if-empty", then no tar should be created.

```
find /app/test -type d  \( -name logs -o -name 'logs*' -o -name 'tmp*' \) -prune -o  -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 tar -cvf /app/test_Backup.tar
```

by the way, your code worked on my raspberry.
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: The other questions from the same user are tagged with [tag:aix], i.e. not Linux. We can't assume they are using GNU tools,

Comment: tried with `--no-run-if-empty` but I don't see any error or pointers the commands simply run while the output of the find and that of the tar do not match.

Comment: The operating system I'm facing the issue is `Linux`

Comment: Does this print the files spaced?
`find /app/test -type d  \( -name logs -o -name 'logs*' -o -name 'tmp*' \) -prune -o  -print0 | xargs echo`

and whats in the tar? nothing?
`tar -tvf test_Backup.tar`

Answer (score 0):

If your `find` command is generating *many* pathnames, then `xargs` will more likely than not execute `tar` several times.  Each execution of `tar` would overwrite the archive created in the last execution of `tar`, so that in the end, you are left with an archive consisting of the last batch of files that `find` found.

Assuming that your are on AIX (as you tagged your previous question with [aix](/questions/tagged/aix)), what you want to do is probably to write the paths to a file and then use that file with `tar -L listfile` (the `-L` option of [`tar` on AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/t_commands/tar.html) is given a list file containing the pathnames to archive).

```
find ...as you had... >listfile
tar -cf archive.tar -L listfile
```

Since I don't have access to an AIX system, I can't unfortunately test this.

Comment: The suggestion did not work. I get the below error:  `tar: /home/user1/listfile: Invalid tape length
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.`   Can you please suggest?

Comment: Exactly what version/variant of `tar` are you using? Gnu!tar and AIX!tar are rather different.